# Combining rows in pandas DataFrame by iterating

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

How can I achieve the expected result from the following DataFrame

```
 df
            col_1             col_2    col_3
     0  Non-Saved    www.google.com   20,567
     1             www.facebook.com      
     2             www.linkedin.com      
     3      Saved     www.Quora.com    6,337
     4                www.gmail.com
```

Expected result:

```
            col_1              col_2    col_3
     0  Non-Saved     www.google.com   20,567
                    www.facebook.com
                    www.linkedin.com
     1  Saved          www.Quora.com    6,337
                       www.gmail.com
```

From 5 rows to 2 rows by merging the empty strings in col_1 and col_3. Also, concatenating values in col_2 into one cell. Can anyone help me with an user-defined function to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip()).replace('',np.nan)

df.groupby(df.col_1.ffill())\
  .agg({'col_2': lambda x: ' '.join(x) ,'col_3':'first'})\
  .reset_index()
```

Output:

```
       col_1                                             col_2   col_3
0  Non-Saved  www.google.com www.facebook.com www.linkedin.com  20,567
1      Saved                       www.Quora.com www.gmail.com   6,337
```

Comment: df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip()).replace('',np.nan)

Gives an error: `AttributeError: ('Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas', u'occurred at index NumberOfRequests')`

Comment: Yes, but see this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34324332/6361531)

Comment: You can try '\n'.join(x)

Comment: `col_1              object`
`col_2              object`
`col_3              int64`
`dtype: object`

Comment: I have a slight tricky condition here -> [Combine_rows...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46698514/combining-rows-in-pandas-dataframe-by-comparing-multiple-columns).
Would you mind taking a look once. Meanwhile I am trying as well.