# displaying embedded newlines in a text column of a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, formatting, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to display a DataFrame with a mutiline text column (eg code snippet) in a Jupyter notebook:

```
IPython.display.display(df)
```

Unfortunatelly this does not respect the newlines in the text and turns each cell into a wall of text.

How can I display a dataframe with linebreaks within text cells preserved?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pretty printing newlines inside a string in a Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34322448/pretty-printing-newlines-inside-a-string-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 11):

## Using pandas `.set_properties()` and CSS `white-space` property

My preferred way is to use pandas's [pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.set_properties()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.set_properties.html) method and the CSS [`"white-space": "pre-wrap"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space#Values) property:

```py
from IPython.display import display

# Assuming the variable df contains the relevant DataFrame
display(df.style.set_properties(**{
    'white-space': 'pre-wrap',
})
```

To keep the text left-aligned, you might want to add `'text-align': 'left'` as below:

```py
from IPython.display import display

# Assuming the variable df contains the relevant DataFrame
display(df.style.set_properties(**{
    'text-align': 'left',
    'white-space': 'pre-wrap',
})
```

Comment: That looks great. I need to rry it out

Answer (score 5):

Try @unsorted's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34322448/pretty-printing-newlines-inside-a-string-in-a-pandas-dataframe):

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML
def pretty_print(df):
    return display( HTML( df.to_html().replace("\\n","<br>") ) )
```

Comment: Thanks! That does solve the newline problem, but it makes all the text lines right-justified again. I am currently using Styling (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html) to force left justification. Is there a way to make the cells left justified with .to_html()? I see a way to make column headers left-justified, but not body cells.