# pandas dataframe and multi line values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Good day,

Is it possible to get multi line cell output when using pandas DataFrame in a shell? I understand the whole row will have height more than 1 char, but that's what I actually want.

Example:

```
data = [
       {'id': 1, 't': 'very long text\ntext line 2\ntext line 3'},
       {'id': 2, 't': 'short text'}
       ]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.set_index('id', inplace=True)
print(df)
```

and want to get output:

```
id                  t
1      very long text
       text line 2
       text line 3
2      short text
```

instead of

```
id                                         t
1     very long text\ntextline 2\ntext line3
2                                 short text
```

Comment: You can use Python's tabulate https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/ to solve the problem: from tabulate import tabulate; html_table = tabulate(df, df.columns, tablefmt='html')

Answer (score 13):

Look at this answer from @unsorted here [Pretty printing newlines inside a string in a Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34322448/pretty-printing-newlines-inside-a-string-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

here it is with you example:

```
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display, HTML

def pretty_print(df):
    return display(HTML(df.to_html().replace("\\n","<br>")))

data = [
       {'id': 1, 't': 'very long text\ntext line 2\ntext line 3'},
       {'id': 2, 't': 'short text'}
       ]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.set_index('id', inplace=True)

pretty_print(df)

         t
id  
1   very long text
    text line 2
    text line 3
2   short text
```

Answer (score 8):

You will get your expected result with

```
df.t.str.split("\n", expand=True).stack()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can unnest your string with `Series` after `str.split`

```
df.set_index('id').t.str.split(r'\n').apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index(level=1,drop=True).to_frame('t')
Out[177]: 
                 t
id                
1   very long text
1      text line 2
1      text line 3
2       short text
```