# Review the \n (newline) values with proper representation in DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, newline

I have this:

```
test = ['hey\nthere']
Output: ['hey\nthere']
```

And when I insert in into the DataFrame it stays the same way:

```
test_pd = pd.DataFrame({'salute': test})
Output:

        salute
0   hey\nthere
```

But I want it to be shown properly:

```
  salute
0 hey
  there
```

How could I do this?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34322448/pretty-printing-newlines-inside-a-string-in-a-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working in jupiter notebook / google colab CSS customization can be used:

```
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display

test = ['hey\nthere']

test_pd = pd.DataFrame({'salute': test})

display(test_pd.style.set_properties(**{
    'white-space': 'pre-wrap'
}))
```

Alternative solution involves replacing newline character with `br` HTML element:

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML

test = ['hey\nthere']

test_pd = pd.DataFrame({'salute': test})

def pretty_print(df):
    return display( HTML( df.to_html().replace("\\n","<br>") ) )

pretty_print(test_pd)
```