# pandas split cell into half

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, split

I have a df that looks like this:

df:

```
col_a  col_b
121    abc\ndef
```

what I am trying to achieve is:

result_df:

```
col_a  col_b
121    abc
       ---
       def
```

in a single row, with both values present in a single cell separated by a line. Is this possible?

Comment: `abc\n---\ndef` is the value of result you expected, cause what you expect related to formatted output but not to the real value itself

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest this would still show the char '\n' in the output.

Comment: that's what I've written about, but you didn't "read"

Comment: I think this question is similar to [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34322448/pretty-printing-newlines-inside-a-string-in-a-pandas-dataframe)